# Error in implementation of FT without using the 'fft' function

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to implement Fourier Transform (FT) without using the `fft` function.

Here is my code:

```
img = imread('blackandwhite.png');
f = img;
N = 10;
output = zeros(N,N);
summation = 0;
for u = 0 : N-1
    for v = 0 : N-1
        for x = 0 : N-1
            for y = 0 : N-1
                expo = (cosd(2*180*(u*x + v*y)/N)) - (sind(2*180*(u*x + v*y)/N)*1i);
                fxy = f(x+1, y+1) * expo;
                summation = summation + fxy;
            end
        end
        output(u+1, v+1) = summation;
        summation = 0;
    end
end
```

I get this error:

> Error using  `*`
>   Complex integer arithmetic is not supported.
>
> Error in `Hw1` (line 11)
>   `fxy = f(x+1, y+1) * expo;`

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: I didn't look closely into your issue but using `double` data type will definitely get rid of the error. i.e. `img=im2double(imread('blackandwhite.png'));`

Comment: ok, i will try this ,but why double type will be rid of error ?

Comment: It's just the way it is. Take a look at [*this answer*](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/233288-error-using-complex-integer-arithmetic-is-not-supported#answer_188992) by W. Robertson on MATLAB Answers.